# addTextChangedListener doesn't work for space or backspace etc

Tags: android, sockets, text, touch, addtextchangedlistener

I'm writing an android app that sends your inputs to the pc via socket programming. I can send all the characters that you write in a textarea such as 'a','1','+' etc. but cannot send "space" or "backspace" when i touch the space on the keyboard from the screen it shuts down the app. anyone can tell why ? or any other function suggestions that i can use ?

This is the code i wrote for the situation.

```
etTextArea.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            int x =0;
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                char characters ;
                MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
                characters = etTextArea.getText().charAt(x);
                messageSender.execute(String.valueOf(characters));

                /*if (characters == ' ')
                {
                    Toast.makeText(KeyboardActivity.this, " space ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    messageSender.execute(String.valueOf(karakterler));
                }*/

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                x++;
            }
        });
```

Any help would be great, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

If text has changed it should work. Also for key events you can use for example:

```
view.setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                presenter.onBackClicked()
                return@setOnKeyListener true
            }
            return@setOnKeyListener false
        }
```

Comment: what is the presenter here exactly?

Comment: and by the way i have tried to use setOnKeyListener before, it only works if use emulator on my pc and write from hardware keyboard otherwise it doesnt work

Comment: you can replace  presenter.onBackClicked() with your own code, it means that back key was jus pressed.